# Alternating sum of subfactorials: Is there a closed form for this: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(-1)^i\left[\frac{(m-i)!}{e}\right]$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

The problem was to find the number of ways in which $n$ objects in circular arrangement can be placed so that each one has a new object in front of it (assuming a particular, initial arrangement).

There are $n$ objects, $(n-1)!$ ways of permute them (without any restrictions) and $n$ pairs that one has to subtract from those permutations. It's an application of the inclusion/exclusion principle, which leads to the alternating sum of derangements:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-3}(-1)^i\left[\frac{(n-1-i)!}{e}\right]$$

where $[x]$ denotes the nearest integer function.

If $m = n-1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-2}(-1)^i\left[\frac{(m-i)!}{e}\right]$$

In the OIES one can find it as the sequence [A000757](https://oeis.org/A000757)

If $n$ is not too large, to calculate it by hand isn't that bad, but I've been looking for a faster, equivalent way.

Thanks!!